# emacs org-mode characters about unorder list

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I read about the manual about emacs org-mode on chapter 2.7, I wondered to know whether list characteres `+`, `-`, `*` have specific/special meanings. If you know, please tell me! For example, the character `*` means heading, but what about other characters?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsFW6.png)

Comment: Make an example, the character * means heading, what about other characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+, -, and * are the unordered list characters. * is used for headings, but also for an unordered list item.

Here is a link to the docs.

https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get it.